# Flutter error : RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a checkbox list of services.  when i open this page, it returns error.

[image]

```
 List<bool> listBool = [];




 Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 5),
                child: FutureBuilder<Booking>(
                  future: getBookingById(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.25,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                           itemCount: snapshot.data!.addons.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context,index){
                             return ListTile(
                               leading: Checkbox(
                                 activeColor: const Color(0xFF4B0082),
                                 onChanged: (value) {
                                   setState(() {
                                       listBool[index] = value!;
    
    
                                   });
                                 },
                                 value: listBool[index],
                               ),
                               title: Text(
                                 '${snapshot.data?.addons[index].name}',
                                 style: const TextStyle(
                                   color: Color(0xFF0A2544),
                                   fontSize: 18.0,
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                 ),
                               ),
                               subtitle: Text(
                                 "${snapshot.data?.addons[index].description} ",
                               ),
                             );
                      })
                      );
    
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

the error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      _ServiceListPageState.serviceView.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:apex/screens/service_list_page.dart:193:45)
```

I got that error and that is because of the index for value.
the error's line: `value: listBool[index],`

Comment: Try with checking response data, then provide it to the items,

Comment: the problem is not  in the data

Comment: You can add condition **snapshot !=null** and also check **listbool !=null**

Comment: How do you add items to `listBool` list? It seems that you are trying to access `listBool[x]` and `x` is not a valid item index.

Comment: exactly i have just two items, how can i fix it